# Different ways to inject dependencies

Tags: angularjs

When writing ex. directives I can reference/inject dependencies both in directive factory function like:

```
app.direcive('directiveName', function ($http) {
... };
```

or in controller

```
app.directive('directiveName, function () {
    ...
    controller: function ($http),
    ...
};
```

Also today I've read this [post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2709-directive-controllers-can-use-dependency-injection-in-angularjs.htm) which made me think what's the difference between those two approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways. None are right or wrong. This is style. Use one way for a project, for clarity and consistency.

This is what I would suggest:

```
YourController.$inject = ['http'];
function YourController($http) {}

function yourDirectiveName() {
    return {
        controller: YourController,
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        bindToController: true
    }
}

app.directive('yourDirectiveName', yourDirectiveName);
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it does not answer my question. Also what is the advantage in using your suggestion (apart from testability)?

Comment: OK. I read your question, to paraphrase, as: "Should I inject Directive Controller dependencies into the Controller -- or into the Directive that the Controller belongs to?". Can you please clarify the question you are asking?

Comment: You might missed that part "... what's the difference between those two approaches?". I know that I can achieve the same thing but was hoping for some insight into how Angular deals with DI that's defined in directive's factory function / controller definition.

Comment: The difference is style only. One is not more correct than the other. It is about how far do you want to separate your concerns? In my example above I have the `controller` take care of annotating its own dependencies. This is a style choice, as I stated in my answer.

Comment: There is also the difference 'minification issues'

Comment: Yes. Uglification will be an issue if you don't manually annotate your injectors or use something like `ng-annotate` at build time. Again, this is style: Do you want to manually annotate or use `ng-annotate`? It is very subjective. There is no right or wrong answer.

Answer (score -1):

I always this way only to add dependencies

app.directive('directiveName', function ($http) {
... };

But that post was good Going through it